# Invalid revision: 3.18.1-g262b901-dirty

Tags: react-native, android-studio, cmake

I have a React Native app that need CMake version 3.18.1-g262b901 to run.
However, it returns with the error

> Invalid revision: 3.18.1-g262b901-dirty

I tried using the latest version and the version before 3.18 but it still required version 3.18 to run.

Comment: In git `dirty` suffix means that you have some **local changes** in the repo. You could run `git status` and it should list you that changes.